# Reactive form in Angular with checkbox in each row of table

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to build a reactive form having table and each row containing checkbox. The rows in the table are populated from an api and checkbox is created dynamically.

Functionality is working as expected but in the console getting below error. Help me understand the issue here. Thanks.

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1tty11

Code:
https://github.com/gauravkumarsingh232/reactive-form-angular

```
ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

   Example:

   
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
  <input formControlName="firstName">
</div>

In your class:

this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
   firstName: new FormControl()
});
```

Comment: I have looked and checked the verified answer before posting my question here. I have  [formGroup] in the form and defined [formControlName] in the component. But it did not help.

Comment: check now https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lkyznb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: what is the change? @AmanSharma

Comment: declaring `formGroup` in the `ngOnInIt()`

Comment: Thanks @AmanSharma.